# TS2322: Type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to type 'Foo & Bar'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to store a item in an object where the object key is the discriminator of the type.

**See edit below.**

Here is a simple example:

```js
type Foo = {
  id: 'foo'
}

type Bar = {
  id: 'bar'
}

type Container = {
  foo: Foo
  bar: Bar
};

const container: Container = {
  foo: { id: 'foo' },
  bar: { id: 'bar' },
};

function storeValue(value: Foo | Bar) {
  container[value.id] = value; // <= Error happens here. See below.
}
```

Here is the complete error I get

```
TS2322: Type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to type 'Foo & Bar'.
   Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Foo & Bar'.
     Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
       Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
         Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'.
```

I tried something like this:

```
type Container = {
  [key in (Foo|Bar)['id']]: FooBar | undefined
}
```

With this, the error is gone... But then it allows something like this (assigning a Bar in container.foo):

```
function storeValue(value: Foo | Bar) {
  container.foo = value; // OK... but it shouldn't be.
}
```

Is there a way to infer the type from the `key` ?

```
type Container = {
  [key in (Foo|Bar)['id']]: ??? | undefined // <= Here, infer the type based on the `key`
}
```

I read the doc, the FAQ, tried a lot of things, read a lot of SO posts, GitHub issues... I didn't found anything.

**Edit: Other example** (still simplified, but closer to my use case. FYI I'm using Twilio Video)

```
type DataPublication = {
  kind: 'data';
  // other props
}

type AudioPublication = {
  kind: 'audio';
  // other props
}

type VideoPublication = {
  kind: 'video';
  // other props
}

type Publication = DataPublication | AudioPublication | VideoPublication;

class Whatever {
  publications: {
    data: DataPublication | undefined
    audio: AudioPublication | undefined
    video: VideoPublication | undefined
  } = {
    data: undefined,
    audio: undefined,
    video: undefined
  }

  handlePublishedWorking(publication: Publication) {
    switch (publication.kind) {
      case 'data':
        this.publications.data = publication; // publication is narrowed to DataPublication
        break;
      case 'audio':
        this.publications.audio = publication; // publication is narrowed to AudioPublication
        break;
      case 'video':
        this.publications.video = publication; // publication is narrowed to VideoPublication
        break;
    }
  }

  handlePublishedNotWorking(publication: Publication) {
    this.publications[publication.kind] = publication;
  }
}
```

Comment: your object key , e.g. `foo` is not the type discriminator `Foo`. it sounds like you're looking to inspect the typescript type at compile time to change a runtime prop..

Comment: can you add a `kind: string` prop to `Foo` and `Bar` to discriminate with? Your types are identical. It might also be useful to know your use case as there may be a better approach

Comment: I added my use case.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Your code examples don't even compile. Please edit your question with a Minimal Verifiable Complete Example.

Comment: No need to be rude. I updated my question to fix the code example. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you try to rely on runtime information to do the discrimination.

TypeScript does not exist in runtime. At runtime it is only JavaScript.

```
function storeValue(value: Foo | Bar) {
  container[value.id] = value;
}
```

The only information TypeScript knows about `value.id` at this line is that it can be either `foo` or `boo`.

It cannot evaluate the value and assume the right type because it can change.

Therefore, `container[value.id]` has type `container['foo'] | container['boo']`,
thus the error you saw.

You need to tell TypeScript which type it will be.

One way to do it is by control flow:

```
type Foo = {
  id: 'foo'
}

type Bar = {
  id: 'bar'
}

type Container = {
  foo: Foo
  bar: Bar
};

const container: Container = {
  foo: { id: 'foo' },
  bar: { id: 'bar' },
};

function storeValue(value: Foo | Bar) {
  if (value.id === 'foo')
    container['foo'] = value;
  else
    container['bar'] = value;
}
```

You can see that the `else` case TypeScript can properly analyze that only `bar` is the possible value thus perform the correct type checking.

Comment: "Therefore, `container[value.id]` has type `container['foo'] | container['boo']`, thus the error you saw."... This single phrase makes the whole thing much more easier to understand. Thank you.